# nvmem device tree naming pattern

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, sysfs, device-tree

In the [nvmem.yml](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/nvmem/nvmem.yaml) there is

```
properties:
  $nodename:
    pattern: "^(eeprom|efuse|nvram)(@.*|-[0-9a-f])*$"
```

I have a hard time finding the pattern in the source code itself.
Where can I find that the nvmem device tree nodename must be 'eeprom' or 'efuse' or 'nvram'.

Answer (score 0):

Device tree node names are communicated to the kernel from the boot firmware, so these are not defined inside the kernel source.

The pattern containing the `@` sign is typical for OpenFirmware. Unless your machine boots from OF, it is unlikely that you have any device tree nodes that match here.

The device-tree code still exists on ACPI based systems, as it allows attaching properties to ACPI device nodes, this is used mostly in embedded systems though (e.g. I have an embedded PC here that uses such a property to disable OTG mode and superspeed in the USB device controller).